# Type or namespace could not be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to SQL to connect my database to my home page. I created my datacontext (named businessModel.dbml) In it I have two tables named Category and Business.

In home controller I reference the model and attempt to return to the view the table:

```
var dataContext = new businessModelDataContext();
var business = from b in dataContext.Businesses
select b;
ViewData["WelcomeMessage"] = "Welcome to Jerome, Arizona!";
ViewData["MottoMessage"] = "Largest Ghost Town in America!";

return View(business);
```

and in the view I have this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="WelcomeToJerome.Models" %>
```

and

```
<% foreach (business b in (IEnumerable)ViewData.Model)
           { %>
        <li><%= b.Title %></li>
        <% } %>
```

Yet, in the view business is cursed with the red underline and say's that The type or namespace name 'business' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I doing wrong? This has had me stumped all afternoon.

link to all the code in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/es4RnS2q

Comment: Please add the code for the model.

Comment: It looks like it'd be a capital B: `Business` judging by the table name, but posting the model would help.

Comment: Nick was right, it needed to be a capital B. I can't believe I didn't try that!

Comment: Converted to an answer so we can close this puppy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try capitalizing the B, judging by your table name, it should be `Business` instead of `business`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `WelcomeToJerome.Models` is a namespace from some assembly, which must be referenced in your `Web.config` in order for the ASP.NET compiler to find it. You don't show the `Web.config`, but I'm betting the assembly isn't properly referenced there.